# Minimal set of algebraically independent numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, algorithms, computer-algebra-systems

Suppose we have a set of polynomials $f_1, f_2, \ldots, f_n \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.  Consider the set
$$S := \{\alpha \in \mathbb{C} \; | \; f_i(\alpha) = 0 \text{ for some } i \}$$
of complex roots of these polynomials.  Then $S$ is a finite set and consequently $V := \operatorname{span}_\mathbb{Q} S$ is a finite-dimensional vector space.  (This sort of situation comes up for instance when performing calculations in representation or invariant theory with a computer).

Often such a list will come out of a computer in a form which is sub-optimal -- for instance, it might talk about the numbers such that $\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0$ and the numbers such that $\beta^2 - \beta + 1 = 0$, when it would be much nicer simply to refer to the numbers $\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0$ and then the numbers one more than those.

Is there a nice algorithm for calculating $\dim_\mathbb{Q} V$, or for reducing the number of $f_i$ in such a list?  Better yet, is there a built-in command to do this in any software?

Comment: Not so fast: if $\alpha^2 + \alpha + 1 = 0$ and $\beta^2 - \beta + 1 = 0$, it could be that $\beta = \overline{\alpha} + 1$ instead of $\alpha + 1$.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't phrase that quite right.  What I really meant was that it would be better to speak of $\{\alpha \; | \; f(\alpha) = 0\}$ and $\{\alpha + 1 \; | \; f(\alpha) = 0\}$ rather than $\{\alpha \; | \; f(\alpha) = 0\}$ and $\{\beta \; | \; g(\beta) = 0\}$.

Comment: If you've seen a computer-generated character table for a finite group you'll see why this would be nice sometimes.